# Analytic subvariety in complex manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, projective-space

I am trying to figure out a statement in a textbook

"If $M$ is any complex manifold of a projective space $\mathbb{P}^{n}$, $V\subseteq M$ an analytic subvariety of dimension $k$, then we can find a linear subspace $\mathbb{P}^{n-k}$ of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ meeting $V$ in isolated points."

Why should this be true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know your background. $V$ will be algebraic (Chow's Theorem) of some degree $d$, and so the generic $\Bbb P^{n-k}$ will intersect $V$ transversely (Bertini's Theorem) in $d$ points. (You can deduce this by applying transversality theory to deduce that the generic $\Bbb P^{n-k}$ is transverse to all the smooth strata of $V$.)

Comment: I am just starting on the Principles of Algebraic Geometry by Philip Griffiths and it is only in the start of this book that he mentioned this result without any reference to Chow's Theorem or Bertini's theorem. Is there any other elementary proof of this result?

Comment: @enoughsaid05: Griffiths and Harris deal with this sort of question numerous times in Chapter 1. Where exactly are you?

Comment: I am in page 64 where it shows that the even Betti numbers of a complex submanifold of a projective space are positive.

Comment: This follows from their discussion on earlier pages — see pp. 49-61. The right background for this, which they more or less assume, is the basics of transversality theory. You might want to take a look at Guillemin and Pollack to get the intuition for this. The basic fact needed for your question is easier: If you vary the linear spaces $\Bbb P^{n-k}$ in $H_{2n-2k}(\Bbb P^n,\Bbb Z)$, the generic one is transverse to any given submanifold of $\Bbb P^n$.